# Duplicated error messages in grails

Tags: grails

Please explain this snippet. How does `g:eachError` work?

```
<g:eachError>
   <dt>
      <a href=""
         onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('${it.getProperties().get("field")}').focus();
           return false;">
         <g:message error="${it}"/>
      </a>
   </dt>
</g:eachError>
```

After this I've got duplicate error messages. Seems it's because of this bug (link below), but I'm using SortedSet.
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8924

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the bean and the field:

```
<g:eachError var="err" bean="${idQuery}" field="idStr">
      <span class="help-inline">${err.defaultMessage}</span>
    </g:eachError>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source code of `ValidationTagLib` class on [github](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/ValidationTagLib.groovy#L180).

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the docs at http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/eachError.html ?

Answer (score 0):

its not show duplicate error messages but show multiple error messages. means you have to define model property and also field property in to error tag